# Database global instance

Tags: android, database, sqlite, android-loadermanager

So I want to have one database instance for all application activities. 
I found the following code:

```
public class MyApplication extends Application {

    private static SQLiteDatabase mDB = null;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
    DataBaseOpenHelper m_OpenHelper = new DataBaseOpenHelper( this );
    mDB = m_OpenHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    }

    public static SQLiteDatabase getDB() {
        return mDB;
    }
}
```

I don`t understand when I can close SQLiteDatabase instance.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This was an issue for me when I first started out with Android, as there aren't many tutorials on the web that describe how to correctly allow access to your database across the entire application (don't ask me why). Here's some sample code that exhibits three possible approaches.

#### Approach #1: subclassing `Application`

If you know your application won't be very complicated (i.e. if you know you'll only end up having one subclass of `Application`), then you can create a subclass of `Application` and have your main Activity extend it. This ensures that one instance of the database is running throughout the Application's entire life cycle.

```
public class MainApplication extends Application {

    /**
     * see NotePad tutorial for an example implementation of DataDbAdapter
     */
    private static DataDbAdapter mDbHelper;

    /**
     * create the database helper when the application is launched 
     */
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        mDbHelper = new DataDbAdapter(this);
        mDbHelper.open();
    }

    /** 
     * close the database helper when the application terminates.
     */
    @Override
    public void onTerminate() {
        mDbHelper.close();
        mDbHelper = null;
    }

    public static DataDbAdapter getDatabaseHelper() {
        return mDbHelper;
    }
}
```

#### Approach #2: have `SQLiteOpenHelper` be a static data member

This isn't the complete implementation, but it should give you a good idea on how to go about designing the `DatabaseHelper` class correctly. The static factory method ensures that there exists only one DatabaseHelper instance at any time.

```
/**
 * create custom DatabaseHelper class that extends SQLiteOpenHelper
 */
public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper { 
    private static DatabaseHelper mInstance = null;

    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "databaseName";
    private static final String DATABASE_TABLE = "tableName";
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

    private Context mCxt;

    public static DatabaseHelper getInstance(Context ctx) {
        /** 
         * use the application context as suggested by CommonsWare.
         * this will ensure that you dont accidentally leak an Activitys
         * context (see this article for more information: 
         * http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/avoiding-memory-leaks.html)
         */
        if (mInstance == null) {
            mInstance = new DatabaseHelper(ctx.getApplicationContext());
        }
        return mInstance;
    }

    /**
     * constructor should be private to prevent direct instantiation.
     * make call to static factory method "getInstance()" instead.
     */
    private DatabaseHelper(Context ctx) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        this.mCtx = ctx;
    }
}
```

#### Approach #3: abstract the SQLite database with a `ContentProvider`

This is the approach I would suggest. For one, the new `LoaderManager` class relies heavily on ContentProviders, so if you want an Activity or Fragment to implement `LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<Cursor>` (which I suggest you take advantage of, it is magical!), you'll need to implement a `ContentProvider` for your application. Further, you don't need to worry about making a Singleton database helper with ContentProviders. Simply call `getContentResolver()` from the Activity and the system will take care of everything for you (in other words, there is no need for designing a Singleton pattern to prevent multiple instances from being created).

Hope that helps!

Comment: Some comments: #1 there is nothing the `Application` class buys you besides, the `onCreate()` called before any of your activities start. `onTerminate()` is never called, so it's useless. #3 If you are not planning to export your data to other apps, a CP is overkill. You can very easily use a Loader directly with a DB, no need for a CP. In short -- singleton is by far the best approach for most cases.

Comment: @NikolayElenkov, I agree 100%. When I wrote this post I didn't know as much about Android but gradually realized all 3 of your points over time :). thanks!

Comment: Thanks for the post. I went for the third approach, however, I would like to load data using LoaderManager in the onCreate() method of the subclassed Application to make accesible (globale) to all activities. The problem is I can't call **getSupportLoaderManager()** from the Application context. Any thoughts? :(

Comment: @M.ES The `LoaderManager` is used to manage `Loader` *across the `Activity and Fragment` lifecycles*. That is, each `Activity` and `Fragment` has its own `LoaderManager` instance... so what you are trying to achieve wouldn't really make much sense. Check out my [**blog post**](http://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2012/07/understanding-loadermanager.html) on the `LoaderManager` for more info.

Answer (score 2):

You dont really need to close it. It will be automatically closed when your process dies. Instead of using the Application object, you can just make your DB helper object a singleton for easier access. BTW, `getWritableDatabase()` and `getReadableDatabase()` are not that different. The only difference is that `getReadableDatabase()` *might* work if you are out of space, while the other will throw an exception.

Answer (score 0):

I dont think this is recommended, if anything you could have a global instance of DataBaseOpenHelper, and call getWritableDatabase() at the points where you actually need the DB. And obviously, only get the writable instance when you need it, otherwise use getReadableDatabase().

I'm not sure exactly the reason behind this, but my guess is that this is an expensive object to get and/or hold on to, so you don't want to create it when the app loads and hold on to a global instance.  Maybe someone else can clarify this point.  I wish the Android docs would explain this better because I also had the impulse to do this.

Comment: that's strange, Alex, it looks like you edited my answer, from the log it looks like you just replaced don't with dont.. not sure why.  And I lost 10 reputation points in the process.  How come?